# How to set a reliable long-term alarm in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm developing an Android app with Phonegap. I need to set a long-term alarm to remind users things like a monthly task.

I was searching plugins for this, but the most popular plugin that I found it doesn't have enough reliability. I've tried to use it, but it only works with short-term alarms and not always.

I asked the developer, and he says that he doesn't know why it fails.

In this situation, I intend to develop my own plugin that help me with this.

I have a medium experience with Android native but I have a question before:

¿Which is the way to set this long-term alarm with high reliability on Android, preferably without services and in the simplest way? ¿It's possible?

Of course, I want to keep the alarms even If the mobile is restarted, If the app is killed and so on.

PD: Thanks and sorry for my english level.

Comment: You are going to have to find, or write, a plugin that uses Android's AlarmManager` and offers the rest of the features that you seek (e.g., "keep the alarms even If the mobile is restarted". "preferably without services" -- unless what you want to do will take less than a millisecond, you should be employing a service.

Comment: As a partial answer to the question, in order to start the alarm when the device is restarted, you would want to implement a broadcast receiver which listens for the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED intent. How you would implement that alarm without a Service, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katzer has rewritten all the plugin in a new version, recently I have been testing it and  it seems that it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, which plugin you tested because you didn't mentioned it.

This Plugin from Katzer is that what you need for your scheduled reminders: 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

This is an example for a scheduled local notification:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         String,  // A unique id of the notification
    date:       Date,    // This expects a date object
    message:    String,  // The message that is displayed
    title:      String,  // The title of the message
    repeat:     String,  // Either 'secondly', 'minutely', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly' or 'yearly'
    badge:      Number,  // Displays number badge to notification
    sound:      String,  // A sound to be played
    json:       String,  // Data to be passed through the notification
    autoCancel: Boolean, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically cancelled when the user clicks it
    ongoing:    Boolean, // Prevent clearing of notification (Android only)
}, callback, scope);
```

This is the way, how you schedule a notification for a date in the future:

```
var now                  = new Date().getTime(),
    _60_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 60*1000);

window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:      1,
    title:   'Reminder',
    message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
    repeat:  'weekly',
    date:    _60_seconds_from_now
});
```

The actual time could be calculated with this script:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

This should help you.

Comment: Yes!! I tested this one. See on issue #405. I've done some tries but it fails many times.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var mm = today.getMonth()-1;` instead of `+`?